# Selecting inside of DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
<ul class="list">
<li><span class="pos"><div class="txt_pos">1</div></li>
<li><span class="pos"><div class="txt_pos">2</div></li>
<li><span class="pos"><div class="txt_pos">3</div></li>
<li><span class="pos"><div class="txt_pos">4</div></li>
<li><span class="pos"><div class="txt_pos">5</div></li>
</ul>
```

and my JS:

```
$(".list span.pos").each(function(i) {
    var newOne = i;
    newRank = getNth(newOne);

    $("> .txt_pos").slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).text(newRank);   

    $("> .txt_pos").slideToggle('slow');                        
});
```

How do I make it select each `li` because right now, it's doing EVERY list item at ONCE. I'm trying to select the child of the `.pos`.

Comment: Have you tried `$(".txt_pos",this)` instead of `$("> .txt_pos")`?

Comment: Few tips - `span` don't have end tag. Do not put `block` elements like `div` in `inline` element such as `span`

Comment: @Engineer. am not i am answer is faster.

Comment: You have not closed any of the `span` tags

Comment: The docs for the child selector recommend you not use this form of the selector `"> .txt_pos"` with no left operand to the `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".list span.pos").each(function(i) {
        var newOne = i;
        newRank = getNth(newOne);

        $(this).children('.txt_pos').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text(newRank);   

        $(this).children('.txt_pos').slideToggle('slow');  //not sure why you're doing this again?
)};
```

Comment: You might want to cache `$(this).children('.txt_pos')`

Answer (score 3):

Use `.children()` to select a child.

```
$(this).children('.txt_pos')
```

Or if you want to select the `li` *(you seem to be saying both)*, use `.parent()`.

```
$(this).parent()
```

Comment: @gdoron: True. There's some bad HTML there, including the `div` presumably inside the `span`.